# ¿por que no puedo crear la relación entre 2 tablas de base de datos?

Tags: sql-server

Estoy tratando de realizar la relación entre 2 tablas en la base de datos, pero no me deja guardarla ya que no entiendo cual es conflicto que hay entre ambas si la tabla de estado ya esta enlazada con pedido y quiero hacer lo mismo con cotización ya que necesito restablecer como tenia la base de datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el error que me aparece es el siguiente :

'Estado' table saved successfully
'Cotizacion' table

- Unable to create relationship 'FK_Cotizacion_Estado'.
  Instrucción ALTER TABLE en conflicto con la restricción FOREIGN KEY 'FK_Cotizacion_Estado'. El conflicto ha aparecido en la base de datos 'PortalVendedor', tabla 'dbo.Estado', column 'IdEstado'.

Comment: tienes datos en tu tablas?

Comment: si las dos tablas tienen datos

Comment: valida que la tabla a la que vas hacer referencia no tenga nulos o no exista el dato como tal, ya que si no lo que estás haciendo es referencia a algo que no existe, ahí es donde te sale el error.